# Visual Studio 2013 terminal application crashes after initiating (empty) std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Here's some simple code that crashes Visual Studio 2013 (VS12) C++ applications -

```
#include <thread>
void empty_thread_function()
{
    // intentionally empty
}
void main()
{
    std::thread my_thread(&empty_thread_function);
}
```

I noticed that if I `detach()` or `join()` in `main()`, after initiating `my_thread` then there is no crash. Also, the program crashes when the main thread returns (regardless of if the empty thread has returned or not).

Anyone have any idea about what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `my_thread.join();` before exiting `main`.

This works because the default behaviour is to call [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) for the application if the `thread` destructor runs when the [thread is still joinable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

> `std::thread::~thread`
>
> Destroys the thread object.
>
> If `*this` has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), `std::terminate()` is called.

Alternatively you can call `detach()`. But as you have noted with the given code snippet, you run into further issues when the main thread exits and you still have other threads running.

The process exits when the main thread (first thread) exits and clean-up (and thus possible crashes) begins before the second thread is complete. Hence it is generally a better idea to wait for you user created threads to complete before exiting the application.

Comment: Two comments - first, with intel's tbb::tbb_thread (which I used prior to c++11) there is no such issue. Second, what if the main thread encounters an exception or exits abnormally? I guess the programmer needs to make sure the join() is executed in those cases too. Alternatively, maybe the detach() is the way to go, that way we are safe even if the main exits abnormally (assuming of course, that no synchronization is needed among the threads).

Comment: I remember watching a video on the `std::thread` implementation and there was a comment made that the committee considered a number of options around the behaviour of `~thread`. IIRC, it was considered the better option to terminate over the others, one of the reasons was it was thus safer and offered a better deterministic resource usage vs. possible leakage etc.